# How to implement a queue with django models /database?

Tags: python, django

I want to implement a queue in my Django app with a model as it's base. I should be able to enqueue to the front of the queue and dequeue old items from the back of the queue based on record's creation time  or link records to each other somehow so you know which record was enqueued first and next and so on. What is the best way of implementing this ?

Is it a good idea to have a `created = models.DateTimeField()` field in the model and scan through the records to find the oldest record(s) and dequeue/`delete()` it/them ? how much would you compromise on performance this way? or is there any better way to link queue items to know in which order they were enqueued ?

Similar questions has been asked before but my requirement is different. I do not need a task queue/job queue like what celery facilitates.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you want simple ordering on your model, you can add a field like `created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)` plus adding `ordering = ('created',)` to the model's Meta class. You can then use `model.objects.first()` and `model.objects.last()` to get the first and last and do what you need to do with them. Depending on how heavily this is going to be used, it may be better from a performance point of view to use Celery or another task queue for this purpose - that's what task queues are intended for.

Answer (score 0):

Your way is fine until you have many concurrent connections. For example, you could come up with something like:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerKey(db_index=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class MessageQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def dequeue(self, count):
        items = (self.order_by('-created')
                 .select_related('content_object')
                 .values('content_object'))
        self.filter(pk__in=items).delete()
        return [item['content_object'] for item in items]


stack = Message.objects.dequeue(3)
```

The woes begin if you have many different processes accessing your heap. It's fairly possible that while you're trying to dequeue some items, another process will put an item on the top. The only right solution in that case is using message brokers like RabbitMQ or ZeroMQ.